# Custom statuses in Liferay's workflows

Tags: liferay

I want to make an workflow that has **other statuses** than the Single Approver workflow, **other than "Update", "Approved"** etc. *Is it possible?*

What I have found on Internet is how to create custom portlets and I am not sure I have to go so far. I understand that these statuses are constants from the **WorkflowConstants.java** file and that it is possible to extend that file in order to add my own constants. *But where should I place that file? What other changes do I have to make to make it work?*

Thank you.

Comment: What approach are you using for your portal extension? Are you using ext environment to extend portal source?

Comment: No, I have not worked with the ext environment yet. I am using Liferay Portal 6.2 Community Edition.

Comment: @ParkashKumar Can I create custom statuses using this approach? Please explain.

Comment: You can override this files using extension environment as well as through hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay has offered different approaches to extend and customize liferay portal depending on the nature and complexity of changes required.

Following are the possible ways:
1. via Extension (ext) environment
2. via Plugins
       i. Portlet
       ii. Hook

Using extension environment, you can simply move that file from portal source to the relevant package of ext and introduce changes.
Lets say, `WorkflowConstants.java` resides at location 
`\portal-service\src\com\liferay\portal\kernel\workflow\WorkflowConstants.java` in portal, so you can copy that file to `\ext-service\src\com\liferay\portal\kernel\workflow\WorkflowConstants.java`.
Make required changes in ext-service file and deploy ext. One restarting container changes will reflect.

Comment: You can't override classes with hooks. You can wrap services and struts actions and replace some of the API implementations using portal.properties, but constants are definitely not modifiable in a hook.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke What about portlets? How can I add constants by creating custom portlets? I am newbie in Liferay as you can see. Thanks.

Comment: You can define your own constants, but that wouldn't be of any use, as Liferay wouldn't know how to translate such a constant to a label for the user. So you will have to create an extension environment.

Comment: @Tobias Liefke, that's why I said, I am sure about hooks. I am working on the extension environment. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: Looks like ext plugins are deprecated on Liferay 7.1. Will this work on portlets ?

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro: I am yet to work on Liferay7, therefore can't stand about it.